# Better way to get number of bits different between two 128-bit MySQL binary values?

Tags: mysql, binary, bit-manipulation, xor, hamming-distance

I'm [using](http://tech.jetsetter.com/2017/03/21/duplicate-image-detection/#mysql-bit-counting) a MySQL binary column (`tinyblob`) to store a 128-bit perceptual image hash for about 200,000 images, and then doing a SELECT query to find images whose hash value is within a certain number of bits different (the [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) is less than a given delta).

To count the number of bits different, you can XOR the two values and then count the number of 1 bits in the result. MySQL has a handy function called [`BIT_COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#function_bit-count) that counts the number of 1 bits in an unsigned 64-bit integer.

So I'm currently using the following query to split the 128-bit hash into two 64-bit parts, doing the two XOR and `BIT_COUNT` operations, and adding the results to get the total bit delta:

```
SELECT asset_id, dhash8
FROM assets
WHERE
    BIT_COUNT(CAST(CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(dhash8, 1, 8)), 16, 10)
        AS UNSIGNED) ^ :dhash8_0) +    -- high part
    BIT_COUNT(CAST(CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(dhash8, 9, 8)), 16, 10)
        AS UNSIGNED) ^ :dhash8_1)      -- plus low part
    <= :delta                          -- less than threshold?
```

But doing a substring, and especially converting it to a hex string and back is kind of annoying (and inefficient). Is there a better way to do this using MySQL?

Comment: You could store it as two UINT64 instead...

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair call -- I hadn't considered changing how we store it.